# Как правильно оформить HashMap?

Tags: android

```
{
    "locations": [{
        "_id": null,
        "coords": {},
        "name": null,
        "placeType": null
    }]
}
```

Как добавить значение в параметр placeType используя HashMap глядя на этот json?

Comment: а не лучше здесь оформить data class?

Comment: Как это? не понял я чего то...Тут проблема в том что locations имеет массив. Если бы не было [] этиз знаков. То я бы добавил без проблем. А так запрос не проходит, так как я не так оформляю запрос

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Попробуйте перевести **Json** в **HashMap**, а дальше уже без проблем добавляйте значения в карту.

```
public Map<String, Object> toMap(JSONObject object) throws JSONException {
    Map<String, Object> map = new HashMap<String, Object>();
    Iterator<String> keysItr = object.keys();
    while(keysItr.hasNext()) {
        String key = keysItr.next();
        Object value = object.get(key);
        if(value instanceof JSONObject) {
            value = toMap((JSONObject) value);
        }
        map.put(key, value);
    }
    return map;
}
```